# What is the best way to have recyclerview list in android backed by table in db

Tags: android, android-contentprovider, android-recyclerview

What is the best way to have recyclerview list in android with database of maximum 200 records.
So that whenever there is change in database, it gets reflected on UI automatically.

Possible solutions are using content provider and content observers
or using localbroadcastmanager etc.

Comment: The efficient way is to use content provider and do the task in different Thread other than UI

Comment: Checkout Loaders http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/reference/android/content/Loader.html